# What does 'staggering than 'X' amount' mean?

Tags: conjunctions

I read the sentence on [Mirror.co.uk](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/technology-science/technology/iphone-flappy-bird-mystery-surrounds-3132762)

> *Mystery surrounds the withdrawal from sale on eBay of an iPhone complete with the Flappy Bird app - which was fetching a **staggering than $94,000.***

*"...a **staggering than** $94000?"* The conjunction 'than' is used for comparison. What does it compare with $94000 here?

This would have meant better to me - *"...which was fetching a staggering $94000."* Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be a misspelling of "then":

> *which was fetching a staggering then $94,000*

(meaning, *$94K, at the time the auction was withdrawn*).

Sometimes the word "then" is used that way. For example, in a similar fashion, one [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=ucoyecz8TqcC&q=%22a%20then%20%2410000%22&dq=%22a%20then%20%2410000%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Kir6UpHqB8epyAH7k4CQAw&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAg) mentions:

> *Bill was set to do a then "$10,000 Pyramid" segment*

(The show is now called $25,000 Pyramid, but it was formally called $10,000 pyramid.)

Another [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=miUE84zlgHYC&pg=PA209&dq=%22a%20then%20one%20hundred%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=byv6Upz2JaiiyAGY0YG4Aw&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22a%20then%20one%20hundred%22&f=false) mentions when God was speaking to

> *a then one-hundred-year-old Abraham*

meaning, God was talking to Abraham at the time when he was 100 years old.

I'm not saying that I prefer this theory over the hypothesis offered by oerkelens (I don't), but I do think that, on an English learner's forum, there might be some value in explaining how *then* can be used in this manner.

Comment: I like the creativity of this option :)

Comment: It would be weird to see "then $94,000". Even in historical contexts where a dollar had a very different value worth noting, I'd expect something else, e.g. "In 1872, mailing a letter cost $0.02, worth $1.50 in today's money" or "An egg costs 1 quadrillion Zimbabwean dollars due to massive inflation". Also I want to say it'd be hyphenated, `then-"$10,000 Pyramid"`

Comment: @TimS. - I initially thought it would be hyphenated, too, but the few instances I found omitted the hyphen: _a reference made with regard to a then forty-one year old..._. Since reading your comment, though, I managed to find a few with the hyphen included, e.g.: _He was a then-forty-two-year-old veteran, a smart pitcher._ One reference even puts the _then_ (and corresponding _now_) in quotes: _its growth from a "then" ten-mile railroad to its "now" grand proportions of 4,786 miles_.

Comment: This option is...not impossible, but certainly quite improbable, I think. The "was fetching" construct (i.e. the use of the imperfect tense) already implies that the figure given is from the time the auction was withdrawn.

Comment: @Kyle - I agree. In fact, I would expect that if this were really the case, it would be worded as: _which was fetching a then-staggering $94,000_, not _a staggering then $94,000_. Still, there's a typo buried in that original somewhere...

Answer (score 6):

I would assume that something went wrong when somebody edited the line from:

> [...] was fetching more than $94,000.

to

> [...] was fetching a staggering $94,000.

The `than` should certainly not be there, it seems a mistake on the site.

Side note: In your line without *than*, you are missing the article `a` :)

Comment: Trust me, I had initially put that! Thanks. Edited!

Comment: Yeah, ELL ate it when you posted :P Na, I see plenty of people missing out on articles, but by now I don't expect it to be anything but a typo from you :)

Comment: Considering their motto: *Real news, real entertainment ... in real time,* I think this could happen. :)

Comment: I think it's a bit too soft to say that this "seems" to be a mistake; this is **definitely** not correct usage.